# Unable to use Flyway with gradle to create migrations on sql server

Tags: jdbc, gradle, flyway

I'm very new to using flyway and currently I'm trying to create database migrations using it for sql sever. We use Gradle in our project, so I'm trying to use the flyway plugin for gradle.

I have downloaded the JDBC driver for sql server from here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11774

This is how my gradle flyway task looks like:

```
flyway {
    driver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
    url = 'jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;Databasename=testing'
    user = 'testdev'
    password = 'testdev'
}
```

The exception I'm getting when I execute gradle FlywayInfo :

```
Caused by: com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc
 connection from DataSource
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUti
ls.java:52)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1174)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.info(Flyway.java:981)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$info.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.gradle.task.FlywayInfoTask.run(FlywayInfoTask.g
roovy:31)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.gradle.task.FlywayInfoTask$run.callCurrent(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.gradle.task.AbstractFlywayTask.runTask(Abstract
FlywayTask.groovy:74)
        ... 79 more
```

Let me know what I'm missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: I have no experience with SQL Server with Flyway, but did you add a SQLServerDriver as a dependency for a buildscript?

Comment: Yes, I had added the dependency for SQLServerDriver. I found the fix, was using the incorrect url, the correct one is:
url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;Databasename=testing'

Comment: You can probably answer to your own question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I had added the dependency for SQLServerDriver. I found the fix, was using the incorrect url, the correct one is: url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;Databasename=testing'